# Difference between :d[count] and d[count]

Tags: vim

As a novice vim user, I used `d[count]<Enter>` to delete lines.
It striked me as odd that there were always **count+1** lines deleted.
If I wanted to delete 2 lines, I typed `d1`, 3 lines took `d2`, ...

I finally took the time trying to understand why and it appears I should have been using `:d<count>`.

That does beg for the question though, why is `:d1<Enter>` <> `d1<Enter>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`d<count>` in normal mode doesn't do anything, because the count isn't followed by a motion. So presumably you've been hitting `d<count><Enter>`, in which case the motion associated with `d` is `<count><Enter>`, which moves `<count>` lines downward. Since `<Enter>` is a linewise motion, the `d` will also be linewise, deleting all lines from the current one to the line `<count>` downward, inclusive.

The command you *actually* wanted is `<count>dd`.

Comment: good explanation, I was trying `d1` repeatedly in normal mode with no success...I didn't know about `<count>dd` I was using `d<count>j` or `d<count>k` always missing the count by one.. The funny thing with Vim is that there is always multiple ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 4):

[`d{motion}`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#d) deletes the text that `{motion}` moves over. When you type `3<ENTER>`, the cursor moves 3 lines below the current and therefore `d3<ENTER>` deletes that area.

[`:d[count]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3ad) simply deletes `[count]` lines.

The difference is that `{motion}` is not the same as `count`.

To get around that, you could use the [`visual`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-mode) mode and select what you're going to delete and then simply press `d`.